# Redirect to Object Record page on Salesforce Mobile from Slack App

Tags: lightning-record-page, salesforce-mobile-app, slack, slack-salesforce-app, slack-app

I have requirements from Customer :
**Create a button on Object Record Page which sends message with link to this Record in Slack** ,
So **when a user clicks on it , It will open the record page in Salesforce Mobile**.

I saw this documentation --  [slack](https://www.salesforcereader.com/2021/07/slack-for-salesforce-developers.html#ConnectingtoSalesforcefromSlack) --,
[image]
However I can not find anything about it.

**Is it possible at all ??**
Maybe someone has already done something similar ?

Any help will be appreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible.

All you need to do is send a message to the Slack in the [Block UI format](https://api.slack.com/block-kit) from apex.

Then make sure you have added [interactivity](https://api.slack.com/block-kit/interactivity) to the button (Sent as a part of block message) and the button url should be something like below

```
salesforce1://sObject/001D000000Jwj9v/view
```

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I was looking for.